# How to display messages from a particular phone number in `ListView`?

Tags: android, listview, sms

I have to display `SMS` messages from a given number in `ListView`.
I have displayed messages from a number that i described in program.
Now i have to get number using `EditText` and display messages from that number.
My `MainActivity.java` is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
List<String> msgList=getSMS();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,msgList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public List<String> getSMS(){
List<String>sms=new ArrayList<String>();
final String SMS_URI_INBOX="content://sms/inbox";
try {
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(SMS_URI_INBOX);
    String[] projection=new String[]{"_id","address","person","body","date","type"};
    Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,"address='+918870346164'",null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int index_Address = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        int index_Person = cursor.getColumnIndex("person");
        int index_Body = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int index_Date = cursor.getColumnIndex("date");
        int index_Type = cursor.getColumnIndex("type");
        do {
            String strAddress = cursor.getString(index_Address);
            int intPerson = cursor.getInt(index_Person);
            String strBody = cursor.getString(index_Body);
            String longDate = cursor.getString(index_Date);
            int intType = cursor.getInt(index_Type);

            sms.add("\n"+strBody+"\n");
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        if (!cursor.isClosed()){
            cursor.close();
            cursor=null;
        }
    }
}catch (SQLiteException e){
    Log.d("SQLiteException",e.getMessage());
}
return sms;
```

}

In this line i have defined the number i want to use
`Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,"address='+918870346164'",null,null);`
Here i have to get the number from user via `TextView`.
Please help

Comment: you want to use EditText value as Number in your query ?!

Comment: yes, i want to use my `EditText` value that i get from other Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to get track with [Android Training](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

But any way [EditText getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText())

```
 EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);

 String address="address='"+et.getText().toString()+"'";

 cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,address,null,null);
```